# Stop Oxygen XML from trying to resolve <xi:include>

Tags: oxygenxml

I have a whole lot of BITS xml files. Most have <xi:include> in them pointing to other files, but those files were not in the set I downloaded. I want to run an xpath on these files but it's throwing up errors on every file with any of these xi:includes.

How can I stop it from trying to resolve these? I know what I'm looking for isn't in those files. There has to be something in the preferences to ignore these kinds of reference tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an “Enable xinclude processing” checkbox in the Oxygen Preferences, maybe you could try unchecking it: https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/25.1/ug-editor/topics/preferences-xml-parser.html#preferences-xml-parser__enable-xinclude

Comment: This feels like when you ask your spouse where the mustard is - and he grabs it from in front of your nose. I _swear_ I looked!

Comment: Funny Oxygen’s Preferences dialog has a quick find field which is useful for cases like this.